# Send email from changed cell value from multiple offset rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to have an email send when a cell value changes in our Excel tracking dashboard in multiple offset rows that are 9,0 from each other.

I have tried defining offset ranges for the Intersect but the code will not run with what I enter. Likewise, I am unable to tranfer this knowldge to the email subject line to take the offset client data for the email.

```
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("J13"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsDate(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hello" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This client is now Committed & Complete and ready for your attention" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Renew As Is?" & vbNewLine & _
              "Adding Changing Groups?"                        
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "abc@xyz.com;IDCardTeam@xyz.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Committed & Complete" & "  " & Range("B9").Value & "  " & Range("C9").Value
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need the worksheet to send an email whenever a target cell has a date entered and grab the associated cusotmer information to populate the email.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next`. Do you get an error message now, and if so what is it? Btw, `Target.Cells.Count` should be `Target.Cells.CountLarge`.

Comment: I do not get an error. This code works as expected. When I try to change it to account for the hundreds of other taget cells is when I experience failure.

Comment: Where is that change? Can you share that code that you've tried?

Comment: Set xRg = Intersect(Range("J13:J5000"), Target.Offset 9,0)

Comment: We want the email to send whenever the target cell (every 10th cell) has a date entered.

Comment: `Target` is the cell that changes. I'm not sure I understand your setup exactly. Maybe add a screenshot of some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite see where the Mail sub refers to the target or the offset, but try this:

EDIT: for completeness' sake, here is the tested code

```
   Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim offsetRow As Long
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
' not required      Set xRg = Intersect(Range("J13"), Target)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J13:J5000")) Is Nothing Then
            If IsDate(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 Then
               targetRow = Target.Row
               offsetRow = Target.Offset(9, 0).Row
               Call something(targetRow, offsetRow)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

Sub something(a As Long, b As Long)
Debug.Print "This is a " & a & " and " & b


End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen, yeah, just realised and corrected. This happens when writing code in the browser <bg>

Comment: Thank you Teylyn. I am getting expression and end of statement errors with your solution. It also does not automatically bring up the email when the value is changed.

Comment: I edited my code shortly after posting it. try the current version.

Comment: added a missing `end if`, but now it runs without error for me

Comment: About your email not working: You need to understand that your email code does nothing with regards to the target or its offset. There is no reference to that. I showed you in my sample code how you can bring the target row and the desired offset row into your email code. But you need to do that before you can use it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. We got it with your solution.